# Working with DataSets

Tags: dataset

I am new to working with datasets, and I know this is relatively basic, but I can not figure out why I keep getting an empty set as my answer?

```
data2 = ResourceData["Sample Data: Animal Weights"]
data2[Select[#BrainWeight > 1000g &],"Species"]
```

And I get an empty box as my answer.

However, an input such as this give the expected answer:

```
data2[SelectFirst[#Species=="AfricanElephant"&], "BrainWeight"]
(* Out: 5712 g *)
```

Comment: Try replacing 1000g with Quantity[1000, "Grams"]

Comment: @M.R., why can't WL understand `1000*grams` means the same as `Quantity[1000, "Grams"]`?  (some have said because zero Fahrenheit doesn't reduce to zero, but that's no different than handling divide by zero as a special case).

Comment: @alancalvitti Here you go: `grams = Quantity[1, "Grams"]; 1000 grams`. Kind of the same as [`Degree`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Degree.html).

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you, being new I thought it just returned the number, I didn't realize it was paying attention to the units!